# What data transfer rate can I get with an SSD and SATA system?

Tags: ssd, sata, data-transfer

I am looking for a solution that can write around 120MB/sec continuously to an SSD drive. Can I get this data transfer rate?

The drive can be formatted in FAT32 or EXT2, and I write to it for say 1 hour (or until it becomes full).

Do you have any suggestion for a drive?

Comment: You do understand SSDs have a write lifespan right? So feeling it up isn't the greatest idea.  More information on the system hardware is required

Answer (score 3):

The majority of modern SSDs of size 200GB and up (size affects write speed) can write over 200MB/sec sequentially, such as for copying files.

If you're looking for a sustained 120MB/s of random/simultaneous writes, that is a different story, but you should probably explain your intended scenario in more detail.